# How to stream real time data (numbers) to Android app?

Tags: java, android, streaming, real-time, inputstream

I'm building an Android app in which I want to display some real time data (updated every second) which I want to stream directly from my server to the App. There will be multiple Apps connected at the same time, which should all get the same stream. I am now looking for a way to do this from both the server and the client/Android side. From the server side I can basically build anything, so I thought I'd start from the client side.

In the Android docs I found the [inputStream class](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html) which I guess is what I need for this. So my first question: **is the inputStream class the right tool for the job?**

If so, I guess I can set it up (found some examples on the net), but from here I'm still unsure of how to build this service from the server side? Do I need to build a simple page which I constantly update, or should I use a messaging lib such as zeromq with multicasting? Any more tips/hints/pointers on which technology to use for the server side would be very welcome as well!

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your data. For example if you need to keep your clients updated on some values, like weather data in a location, a simple polling mechanism will suffice. You would have to build a web page that shows the current values and the clients would have to keep polling and parsing the page in the time intervals desired.

On the other hand, if you've got a stream of binary data that need to be transferred to the client, you would need to do some socket programming. There are tons of samples like [this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/) to help you get started. Also keep in mind that to maintain your sockets with the server, you will have to keep them running in the background as a service.

Comment: The info is updated at least once per second, so I guess polling is out of the question. For this reason I already though I would need to do something using sockets. I've got some experience with zeromq, which makes using sockets very easy. Do you think using a messaging lib such as zeromq is a good idea?

Comment: [this](http://zeromq.org/build:android) link suggests using JeroMQ instead of zeromq for Android use. It seems that the library uses a lot of native JNI stuff. I haven't done much coding with zeromq but your scenario seems to be well handled with Java's out-of-box socket programming libraries.